Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}(x^2+x)=a^2+a$
Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}(x^2+x)=a^2+a$
So from the definition I have $$|x^2+x-(a^2+a)| \lt \varepsilon$$
or
$$|x-a| |x+a+1| \lt \varepsilon$$
Which gives me
$$|x-a| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{|x+a+1|}$$
Which is true for all $|x+a+1| \gt 1$
However, I feel this is missing a lot of substance, any hints?

You can use the triangular inequality, which gives $$|x^2+x-a^2-a|<|x^2-a^2|+|x-a|=|x-a|(|x+a|+1)<\epsilon$$ Then choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{|x+a|+1}$

@BoweiTang How can you choose your $\delta$ to depend on $x$, before you know what $x$ is?

@Misha Lavrov My bad. $\delta=\min{{a, \frac{\epsilon}{|3a|+1}},\frac{\epsilon}{|a|+1}}$

$\frac \epsilon{|x+a+1|}$ is not a constant.  You can't use a variable range to chose a variable.

"So from the definition I have...": you do not have it, you want it.

@
Bowei Tang
When $a=0$, your $\delta=0$, let alone $a<0$. Maybe you want $\delta=\min{{|a|, \frac{\epsilon}{|3a|+1}},\frac{\epsilon}{|a|+1}}$.

First, take $x$ such that $|x-a|<1$, then
$$|x|\leq|x-a|+|a|<1+|a|.$$
For any given $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|a|)}\}$, when $|x-a|<\delta$, we have
$$|x^2+x-(a^2+a)|=|x-a||x+a+1|
\leq(|x|+|a|+1)|x-a|<2(|a|+1)|x-a|
<\epsilon.$$

"So from the definition I have $|x^2+x-(a^2+a)| \lt \varepsilon$": you do not have it, you want it.
For this, by your calculations, if $|x-a|<\delta$, it will suffice that $\delta|x+a+1|<\varepsilon$.
Now if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|x+a+1|=|x-a+2a+1|<\delta+|2a+1|$.
Therefore, to achieve $\delta|x+a+1|<\varepsilon$, it suffices that $|x-a|<\delta$ for some $\delta>0$ such that
$$\delta(\delta+|2a+1|)\le\varepsilon$$
i.e.
$$\delta^2+|2a+1|\delta-\varepsilon\le0$$
i.e.
$$\delta\le\frac{-|2a+1|+\sqrt{(2a+1)^2+4\varepsilon}}2.$$
